# How do display a webpage with a URL containing a key from the database without 404 error

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a page named `story.html` and a `story` node in Firebase realtime database with a key of `12ab34cd`

How do I properly set the hosting rules to not direct the URL "website.com/story/12ab34cd" to a 404 page?

I already did the ff to my `firebase.json` file

```html
{
  "public": "retroscope-root",
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "story/*",
      "destination": "/story.html"
    }
  ],
  "trailingSlash": false,
  "cleanUrls": true
}
```

I still get redirected to a 404 page with the key present

Comment: is it also possible to redirect to the story.html with the URL story.html/12ab34bc?